# JavaScript: Why does a negative number return a positive?

Tags: javascript

Okay I wrote a simple function where if the `number > 0` return it. And if `number < 0` return `-number` (a negative)

In my test: when `number < 0` it returns it as a positive number. Why?

```js
numberFunc = function(number) {
  if (number > 0) return number;
  if (number < 0) return -number;
  return 0;
}

const result = numberFunc(-5);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You wrote a function to compute the absolute value of a number and you're now asking "why does my function work"?  Is that really the case here?

Comment: just make it return your number ! though, I Don't what's the use of your function in that case ??

Comment: Guys, this function was an example use case to ask why  return -number returns a positive. I now see that javascript automatically calculates -- = +

Comment: it's not the problem of JavaScript. In normal mathematics, `-(-1) = 1` anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because, mathematically speaking, `--1 = +1`, so passing `-1` into the line below will return `1`.

```
if (number < 0) return -number;
```

You should just use [`Math.abs()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) instead of writing your own function though.

Comment: You should add where it has that in the code. (Just a suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

`Math.sign(number)` - Use this Math function to determine whether a number is negative, positive or Zero. It will return either a 1, -1 or 0.

```
console.log(Math.sign(3));
// expected output: 1

console.log(Math.sign(-3));
// expected output: -1

console.log(Math.sign(0));
// expected output: 0

console.log(Math.sign('-3'));
// expected output: -1
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign